# How to "shift" a collection/array of Strings?

Tags: java, android

In my Android app i'm storing days of week in a database by creating a `String` from their numeric representation in the `Calendar` class.

For example:

- All days: `"1234567"`
- Monday and Tuesday: `"23"`
- Monday, Wednesday, Friday: `"246"`

etc.

I'd like to create a method that format these `String`s into the following format:

- Source String: `"1234567"`, formatted `String`: `"Mon Tue Wen Thu Fri Sat Sun"`
- Source String: `"246"`, formatted `String`: `"Mon Wen Fri"`

So i came up with the following method:

```
// input is "1234567" for example
public static String formatDays(String input) {
    List<String> dayStringList = new ArrayList<>(input.length());
    char[] days = input.toCharArray();

    for (char day : days) {
        dayStringList.add(DAY_MAP.get(Character.getNumericValue(day)));
    }

    return TextUtils.join(" ", dayStringList);
}
```

`DAY_MAP` looks like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(7);
map.put(Calendar.MONDAY, "Mon");
map.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, "Tue");
map.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, "Wed");
map.put(Calendar.THURSDAY, "Thu");
map.put(Calendar.FRIDAY, "Fri");
map.put(Calendar.SATURDAY, "Sat");
map.put(Calendar.SUNDAY, "Sun");

DAY_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
```

This works fine.

**My problem** is the representation of Sunday in `Calendar` is `1`, so for example, for the value `"1234567"` i'm getting the following formatted `String`:

`"Sun Mon Tue Wen Thu Fri Sat"`

instead of the following:

`"Mon Tue Wen Thu Fri Sat Sun"`

I have no idea how to address this issue, would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change you map to this:

```
map.put(Calendar.MONDAY - 1, "Mon");
map.put(Calendar.TUESDAY - 1, "Tue");
map.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY - 1, "Wed");
map.put(Calendar.THURSDAY - 1, "Thu");
map.put(Calendar.FRIDAY - 1, "Fri");
map.put(Calendar.SATURDAY - 1, "Sat");
map.put(Calendar.SUNDAY + 6, "Sun");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to:

```
dayStringList.add(DAY_MAP.get((Character.getNumericValue(day)%7)+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString.replaceAll("1", "Mon ");
yourString.replaceAll("2", "Tue ");
yourString.replaceAll("3", "Wed ");
yourString.replaceAll("4", "Thu ");
yourString.replaceAll("5", "Fri ");
yourString.replaceAll("6", "Sat ");
yourString.replaceAll("7", "Sun ");

yourString.trim();
```